# Plotting the ConditionalFreqDist of a book

Tags: python, plot, ipython, nltk

Using nltk (already imported). Playing around with gutenberg corpus

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
```

Checked out the fileids, to find one I could play with:

```
gutenberg.fileids()
```

I made a small code to find the most common words (in order to choose a few for the graph)

```
kjv_text = nltk.Text(kjv)

from collections import Counter
for words in [kjv_text]:
    c = Counter(words)
print c.most_common()[:100] # top 100

kjv_text.dispersion_plot(["LORD", "God", "Israel", "king", "people"])
```

Until here it works perfectly. Then I try and implement the ConditionalFreqDist, but get bunch of errors:

```
cfd2 = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((target, fileid['bible-kjv.txt']) 
                           for fileid in gutenberg.fileids() 
                           for w in gutenberg.words(fileid) 
                           for target in ['lord'] 
                           if w.lower().startswith(target))
cfd2.plot()
```

I have tried to change a few things, but always get some errors. Any experts that can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what was wrong:

The fileid in:

```
cfd2 = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((target, fileid['bible-kjv.txt'])
```

should reference to which element it is (in this case the 4th on the list of gutemberg texts.
So the line should instead say:

```
cfd2 = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((target, fileid[3])
```